# Android AlertDialog.Builder and softkeyboard

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog, android-softkeyboard

Is it possible to display automatically the soft-keyboard when the dialog with focused **EditText** created by **AlertDialog.Builder** is shown?

I have seen some some discussion about the topic, but I did not find any working solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)
            SettingsActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

    mDialog = mDialogBuilder.create();

    mDialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {

        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
            dismissSoftKeyboard();
        }
    });

    mPinDialog.show();
    showSoftKeyboard();

}

private void showSoftKeyboard() {
    if (imm != null) {
        imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
    }
}

private void dismissSoftKeyboard() {
    if (imm != null) {
        imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is more than one way to skin a mongoose.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CurrentActivityName.this);
builder.setTitle(“Title”);
builder.setMessage(“Message”);

etc..

//This is the crucial part 
AlertDialog alertDlg = builder.create();
alertDlg.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);

alertDlg.show();
```

It works good in both phone and tablet

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30598731/730807)