# Softkeyboard not showing in AlertDialog for phone only

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-softkeyboard, android-dialog, android-input-method

Why the softkeyboard is showing only on the tablet is a mystery !

Here is the code that I have used.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CurrentActivityName.this);
builder.setTitle(“Title”);
builder.setMessage(“Message”);
final EditText input = new EditText(CurrentActivityName.this);
builder.setView(input);
builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.allow, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
//my code
}
});
builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
//my code
}
});
builder.create().show();
```

I am able to solve it by
[using](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7378788/730807) `postDelayed` with a **number of milliseconds** to post a *Runnable*

```
 input.requestFocus();
 input.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
 @Override
 public void run() {
 InputMethodManager keyboard = (InputMethodManager)
                        getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
 keyboard.showSoftInput(input, 0);
                    }
                },200);
```

**Hard-coded delays** are never recommended because they may introduce *unpredictable behavior* under *different conditions / different devices*.

I am looking for some stable solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem

```
AlertDialog alertDlg = builder.create();

alertDlg.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);

alertDlg.show();
```